# UART signals connected to RJ45 connector?

Tags: schematics

I'm looking at a schematics and found something strange to me.
The schematics connects UART TX/RX signals to a RJ45 connector (leave other unused pins unconnected).
Does anyone know such application?
What's the purpose of such design?
Thanks.

David

I can't get the exactly schematics, just a block diagram like this:

[image]

Comment: You should add that schematic and some info about the device that uses this solution.

Comment: It's not completely unheard of; RJ11 is usually preferred, but RJ45 connectors are cheap and plentiful. Cisco use it for serial console, for example.

Comment: As @pjc50 indicated, it's not unheard of. It's cheap, takes up less space than a DE9 and prevents someone with no clue what they are doing connecting in to the serial port. It also means the equipment manufacturer can sell some over priced serial cables.

Comment: RJ45 is versatile. It isn't used only for ethernet. Carrying RS232 signals is an example, but it is also sometimes used for CAN bus, phone lines, in some houses it is used for distributing TV satellite signal, ... list goes on.

Comment: Just looked on wikipedia and there is this tremendous bit of pedantry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_jack#Unofficial_plug_names

Comment: I've seen plenty of instances of analog security cameras using rj45 plugs and cat5 cable to carry analog video (a simple single-ended to differential balun is all you need for long distance cheap-as analog video cables)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> UART TX/RX signals to a RJ45 connector  [...] Does anyone know such application?

Yes, it is common with various IT devices e.g. terminal servers, some rack-mount and blade servers etc. The specific connections (wiring) between the serial signals (often RS-232 rather than UART level), and the RJ45 pins, can vary.

> What's the purpose of such design?

RJ45 connectors and suitable cabling are common, and take less space on a PCB and back panel than other "standard" serial connectors like DE-9 (some servers which have very limited space on their back panel and PCBs).

Of course using such connectors for a serial interface has the disadvantage that they can be mistaken for an Ethernet connection.

---

Your newly added block diagram does not show the signal labelling expected for a typical RS-232 serial connection from a "UART to RS232" block. Your signals labelled `RX_DP` and `RX_DN` suggest they are the positive and negative *differential* pair for the `RX` signal. RS-232 is not differential. Therefore the various parts of the block diagram do not match (i.e. non-differential RS-232 with (implied) differential signal pin labels on the RJ45 connector). If understanding that detail is important to you, then more information is needed.

Comment: So you mean that they just take the advantage of the "connector" itself, and get rid off anything about Ethernet, right?

Comment: @Shao-WeiWu -- Its rather common to see even other applications using RJ45 since its so cheap and available. Even though its weird, there are many cases that are far from using ethernet that take advantage of the connectors/cabling/tools availability.

Comment: @Shao-WeiWu -  Correct. When used for a typical serial interface, there is no Ethernet being used on that connector. Its purpose is "a serial port" and the equipment expects serial signals. I have seen RS-232, RS-485 and other serial signals connecting to equipment using RJ-45 connectors.

Comment: Modify the block diagram.

Comment: @Shao-WeiWu - The labels on the RJ45 connector in your (updated) diagram *still* do not make sense, compared to the labels on the MAX3218 logic level to RS-232 transceiver - for the reason I explained before (RS-232 does not use differential signalling) and also the RJ45 signal labels suggest they are *both* `RX` (receive) signals, yet your MAX3218 is using both transmit and receive signals.

Comment: [continued] After your updates, this looks like it is becoming a different (and more specific) question, rather than the original (more general) one. If you need help interfacing two *specific* devices, open a new question giving all the details (and links to datasheets, manuals etc) for those two devices. Based on the updated diagrams, it seems *possible* that you are trying to connect two *incompatible* serial devices.

Comment: @SamGibson  Actually, this is the circuit I saw on a platform....not my own design. That's also my question that why the designer connect TX/RX of RS232 to RJ45's RXN/RXP......maybe they just use RJ45 as a conector, and connect to another board with their own defined pin.....just a guess.....

Comment: @Shao-WeiWu - Unfortunately, without the details I asked for, put into a new question, then all I can say is that connecting those signal names does not make sense, based on typical naming conventions.